# Why the struct Client (in coreos/etcd/clientv3/client.go) has the method PUT

Tags: go, etcd

The method PUT is in the interface KV, but the struct Client doesn't implement the the method in interface `KV`. So why it can use the method like this:

```
cli, err := clientv3.New(.....)
cli.Put(...)
```

Comment: Please let us know what kind of research have you already done in the matter, and where it led you. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have set up my etcd cluster and i want to communicate with the etcd server on cloud provider using golang, so i looked for some demos and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

As per [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3#Client)

```
type Client struct {
    Cluster
    KV
    Lease
    Watcher
    Auth
    Maintenance

    // Username is a user name for authentication.
    Username string
    // Password is a password for authentication.
    Password string
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

It means that a `Client` embeds a `KV`. So when calling `Client.Put()` the  `Put()` method of `KV` is promoted and used instead.

Read more: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Comment: thx. I am a golang noob.